# HTML RADIO BUTTON SELECTING BOTH OPTIONS INSTEAD OF ONE

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

Kindly Select the service you require

```
            <input type="radio" id="currConverter" name="currConverter" value="currConverter" />
            <label for="currConverter">Currency Converter</label> <br />

            <input type="radio" id="pbChecker" name="pbChecker" value="pbChecker" />
            <label for="pbChecker">Prize Bond Checker</label> <br />

            <input type="submit" class="submit" />
        </form>
```

I have a form element inside which i have put two radio buttons but want the user to select only one option.When i am clicking on these one by one , both options are getting selected instead of the one on which i clicked.Any solution to this ?

Comment: Both needs to have the same `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link to w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio)

You have to keep same name. in your case:

```html
 
<input type="radio" id="currConverter" name="pbChecker"value="currConverter"/>
            <label for="currConverter">Currency Converter</label> <br />

            <input type="radio" id="pbChecker" name="pbChecker" value="pbChecker" />
            <label for="pbChecker">Prize Bond Checker</label> <br />

            <input type="submit" class="submit" />
        </form>
```